# Generic interface and covariance - fighting the InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

This is probably a classic covariance/contravariance question, it looks like it should work but I'm probably missing a trick.
I'm attempting to return a less derived type from a factory method, but I find that I cannot cast the more specialized concrete instance to a less derived base type.

```
public class AnimalSettings { ... }

public class CatSettings : AnimalSettings { ... }


public interface IAnimalService<TSettings> { ... }

public abstract AnimalService<TSettings> : IAnimalService<TSettings> where TSettings : AnimalSettings { ... }


public class CatService : AnimalService<CatSettings> { ... }
```

Then, in a factory method I have:

```
public static IAnimalService<AnimalSettings> GetAnimalService(AnimalType selector)
{
    switch (selector)
    {
        case AnimalType.Cat:
            return (IAnimalService<AnimalSettings>) new CatService();
            break;
    }
}
```

and the intention is to be able to do the following:

```
var service = MyServiceFactory.GetAnimalService(AnimalType.Cat);
service.DoAnimalBehavior();
```

This compiles fine, but at runtime my code is failing in the attempted cast `return (IAnimalService<AnimalSettings>) new CatService();`, with an `InvalidCastException`.

How should I be casting my more derived type to a less derived type so that callers can use that interfaced base type to invoke functionality?

Changing the cast to `(IAnimalservice<CatSettings>) new CatService()` does work, but it's intended that the caller receives a `IAnimalservice<AnimalSettings>` so that it can handle any sort of animal (In other words, the caller should not be using any of the more specialized types). Should I be specifying an `in` or `out` as part of the generic definition somewhere?

Comment: It should be `IAnimalService<out TSettings>`, but depending on what methods you have in `IAnimalService`, it _might not make sense_ for the cast to succeed, in which case you will get a compiler error when you try to add `out`.

Answer (score 1):

By giving a complete example it would be much easier to help. ;-)

So here is the [working code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zO83F0). And as Sweeper already mentioned, you need to add the `out` parameter at the interface to make it work.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var catService = new CatService(new CatSettings());
        var genericService = (IAnimalService<AnimalSettings>)catService;
        
        genericService.DoAnimalBehavior();
    }
}

public abstract class AnimalSettings
{
    public abstract void DoAnimalBehavior();
}

public class CatSettings : AnimalSettings
{
    public override void DoAnimalBehavior()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Meeoh");
    }
}

public interface IAnimalService<out TSettings>
{
    void DoAnimalBehavior();
}

public abstract class AnimalService<TSettings> : IAnimalService<TSettings> where TSettings : AnimalSettings
{
    private readonly TSettings _settings;
    
    public AnimalService(TSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
    
    public void DoAnimalBehavior()
    {
        _settings.DoAnimalBehavior();
    }
}


public class CatService : AnimalService<CatSettings>
{
    private readonly CatSettings _catSettings;
    
    public CatService(CatSettings catSettings)
        : base(catSettings)
    {
        _catSettings = catSettings;
    }
}
```